# How to write user-defined function in AWS-Glue Script?

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

How can we write user-defined functions in AWS-Glue script using PySpark (Python) on either Dynamic-frame or Data-frame?

Answer (score 2):

dynamicframe doesn't support a UDF exactly the way the Dataframe API supports it. The best you will get is the MAP.apply.

Answer (score -1):

> "AWS Glue does not yet directly support Lambda functions, also known as user-defined functions. But you can always convert a DynamicFrame to and from an Apache Spark DataFrame to take advantage of Spark functionality in addition to the special features of DynamicFrames."
>   - *[AWS Glue Medicaid Python samples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-medicaid.html)*

The AWS Glue Medicaid Python samples (quoted/linked above) include a Spark UDF example:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

chop_f = udf(lambda x: x[1:], StringType())
medicare_dataframe = medicare_dataframe.withColumn(
        "ACC", chop_f(
            medicare_dataframe["average covered charges"])).withColumn(
                "ATP", chop_f(
                    medicare_dataframe["average total payments"])).withColumn(
                        "AMP", chop_f(
                            medicare_dataframe["average medicare payments"]))
medicare_dataframe.select(['ACC', 'ATP', 'AMP']).show()
```

This is just standard Spark code. If you're looking to use Spark SQL, see [this databricks example](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html#user-defined-functions-python).